# PINN : Learning parameters through gradient descent does not lead to appropriate values and decrease quality of learning

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, gradient-descent

I'm trying to implement a Physical Informed Neural Network. The differential part in the loss did bring some improvment (compare to the classical neural net) in the (supposed) unknown area. This unknown area is actually known but I just removed them from training and testing data set to check performance of PINN vs other technics. Here is the code I m using :

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(units=64, activation='relu', input_shape=(2,)),
    layers.Dense(units=64, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(units=1,)
])

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
objective = tf.keras.losses.Huber()
metric = tf.keras.metrics.MeanAbsoluteError()

w_phys = 0.5
w_loss = 1.0 - w_phys

with tf.device('gpu:0'):
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        cumulative_loss_train = 0.0
        metric.reset_states()
        for mini_batch, gdth in dataset:
            with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
                tape.watch(unknown_area_SOCP_tensor)
                tape.watch(mini_batch)

                # Physics loss
                predictions_unkwon = model(unknown_area_SOCP_tensor, training=True)
                d_f = tape.gradient(predictions_unkwon, unknown_area_SOCP_tensor)

                # Physics part with P #
                dp = tf.convert_to_tensor(1/((K*unknown_area_SOCP_tensor[:,0]+L)**2-4*R*unknown_area_SOCP_tensor[:,1]), dtype = np.float64)
                phys_loss_p = 10*tf.cast(tf.math.reduce_mean(tf.math.square(d_f[:,1]**2 - dp)), np.float32)

                # Traditionall loss #
                predictions = model(mini_batch, training=True)
                loss = objective(gdth, predictions)

                # Compute grads #
                grads = tape.gradient(w_loss*loss + w_phys*(phys_loss_p), model.trainable_variables)

            optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))
            cumulative_loss_train += loss
            metric.update_state(gdth, predictions)
            del tape
```

So far so good. K, R and L were fixed parameter.
Next step was to assume they were unknwon and try to figure out if we could learn them.
I tried first by focusing only on R parameter. Here is the code used :

```
with tf.device('gpu:0'):
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        cumulative_loss_train = 0.0
        metric.reset_states()
        for mini_batch, gdth in dataset:
            with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
                tape.watch(unknown_area_SOCP_tensor)
                tape.watch(mini_batch)
                tape.watch(R)

                # Physics loss
                predictions_unkwon = model(unknown_area_SOCP_tensor, training=True)
                d_f = tape.gradient(predictions_unkwon, unknown_area_SOCP_tensor)

                # Physics part with P #
                dp = tf.convert_to_tensor(1/((K*unknown_area_SOCP_tensor[:,0]+L)**2-4*R*unknown_area_SOCP_tensor[:,1]), dtype = np.float64)
                phys_loss_p = 10*tf.cast(tf.math.reduce_mean(tf.math.square(d_f[:,1]**2 - dp)), np.float32)

                # Traditionall loss #
                predictions = model(mini_batch, training=True)
                loss = objective(gdth, predictions)

                # Compute grads #
                grads = tape.gradient(w_loss*loss + w_phys*(phys_loss_p), model.trainable_variables + [R])

            optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables + [R]))
            cumulative_loss_train += loss
            metric.update_state(gdth, predictions)
            del tape
```

But that lead to terrible result (like high loss and poor metric). Worse, the value of R has to be positive, and at the end of the training, R was estimated as a negative value...

I'm quite confident on the equation since I have checked a lot of time, and it seems accurate compared to simulation software I'm using. Moreover, the equation brought value to the learning (as predictions on the unknwon were way better).

Did I miss something here ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I post my answer here in case this may help someone one day.
My issue came from gradient value which was too high. Clipping gradients finally solved my issue.